# How can I implement my own behavior for ctrl-s on UNIX?

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

Is there any way to override ctrl-s ctrl-q implementation on c ? I want to make a shell where when you press ctrl-s it freezes the program. I've seen `int tcflow(int fildes, int action);` but how can I trigger this one when someone presses ctrl-s?

Comment: You might want to tag this `c`, not `shell`, if you're using C as your implementation language (rather than implementing *as a shell script*).

Answer (score 0):

```
stty stop undef start undef
```

disables default ^S + ^Q behavior.

Comment: Ok but how can I detect when ^S or ^Q are pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. The terminal is in charge of this. If your process in the foreground process on the terminal then action is automatically taken. This is what POSIX terminals are intended for. Find resource on the web about "writing a shell".

Comment: This is an exercise on my university. I 've been asked to override ctr-s ctr-q so as to freeze unfreeze just like terminal does.

Comment: @user3638488 the put your terminal in raw mode and you will be able to receive all characters from the terminal...